# Alternative for toast when using widgets in Android 12 as toasts are now truncated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have created an app with a widget. The widget is a simple button that runs a bit of code and then returns a message to the user via a toast. However, I realise in Android 12 toasts are now truncated to two lines and often the message is longer. I'm not keen on snackbars but appreciate my main app can be converted to use them but what should I use to do the same job via a widget?

Snackbars require a layout view to work but I can't figure out how to retirve it from teh widget code. I could use an alertdialogue but although the code compiles they simple don't seem to show up. I'm open to suggestions here...

What is the best way of popping up a message on the homescreen when a widget is pressed? Is there any way of telling the app not to truncate toasts or if not what's the best alternative?

Many thanks

Nat

Comment: Either display a notification or launch an activity. Note that you can use themes to control the look of the activity, so it does not necessarily have to fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks so I tried starting an activity from the widget using pending intent but I couldn't get it to start. I'm not at my pc at the moment to post the code I have but I'll do that tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: So how do you actually start an activity from a widget? I got about as far as... 

Intent myintent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myintent, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

But this doesn't work... Whats the equivelent of 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

when trying to do this from a Widget?

Thanks

Comment: "But this doesn't work" -- what did you do with the `PendingIntent`? If you attached it to the `Notification`, it should be invoked when the user clicks the notification.

Comment: Thank you. It's not being called by a notification. The widget is actually a custom button that runs some code and then displays the output. I need a way of invoking it after the code has run.... Sorry if it's obvious but I couldn't seem to work out how you do that... Maybe I'll post a bit more code to explain...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I failed to scroll up to re-read the question when I posted my last comment. You attach your `PendingIntent` to the button in the app widget using `setOnClickPendingIntent()`. The app widget documentation is not great, but [this section](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#handle-events) has a demonstration.

Comment: Thank you - but is there another way? Basically when I click the button the app connects to a server in the background and retrieves some data... I don;t want anythign to show up on screen until that bit has finished at which point I would display the message on screen. If I attatch the PendingIntent using setonclickpendingintent the message will show straight away. Hope that makes sense. Thank you again.

Comment: "I don;t want anythign to show up on screen until that bit has finished at which point I would display the message on screen" -- that's not practical, sorry. Show the UI with a loading state until your data is ready.

Comment: Oh Rats - at the minute i run the following... 

Maybe a notification could be used to do the same?

Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

  Run my code... do some stuff in the background... 

  //When the code has finished... 
  
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
    //show my toast here...
                    }
                });
  
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out how to do this myself... Its kinda obvious when you know but isn't that always the way?

Create a new activity. You can make it look like a dialog by using this theme in your manifest - android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog". Then from your widget simply call showmessage as outlined below...

```
public void showamessage (String thetitle, String themessage) {

    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(thecontext,MessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TheTitle",thetitle);
    intent.putExtra("TheMessage",themessage);
    pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(thecontext, 0, intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    try {
        pendingIntent.send(thecontext, 0, intent);
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        System.out.println( "Sending pendingintent failed: " );
    }
}
```